# BST table implementation segfault (C)

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, associative-array

I've been trying to implement an associative array (int -> int) in C using binary search trees. However, my current implementation reliably produces a segfault, and I'm not quite sure why. I apologize if the problem is something very simple I just overlooked.

Code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct tree {
        int key;
        int value;
        struct tree *a;
        struct tree *b;
};

int summon (struct tree *t, int key) {
        if (t == NULL) {
                fprintf(stderr, "%s", "Key not in tree");
                exit(-1);
        } else {
                if (t -> key < key)
                        return summon(t -> a, key);
                else if (t -> key > key)
                        return summon(t -> b, key);
                else
                        return t -> value;
        }
}

struct tree _make (int key, int value) {
        struct tree ret;
        ret.key = key;
        ret.value = value;
        ret.a = ret.b = NULL;
        return ret;
}

void cast (struct tree *t, int key, int value) {
        if (key == t -> key) {
                t -> value = value;
        } else if (key > t -> key) {
                if (t -> a == NULL) {
                        struct tree n = _make(key, value);
                        t -> a = &n;
                } else {
                        cast(t -> a, key, value);
                }
        } else {
                if (t -> b == NULL) {
                        struct tree n = _make(key, value);
                        t -> b = &n;
                } else {
                        cast(t -> b, key, value);
                }
        }
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
        struct tree h = _make(5, 2);
        cast(&h, 16, 43);
        printf("%d", summon(&h, 16));
        return 0;
}
```

I'm using gcc on Ubuntu; gdb is **not** being helpful.

Comment: in the function _make, you try to return a structure, which is hold on stack.

Comment: @TomKuschel that's valid... it is in `cast` where it goes wrong.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) variable names, field names, parameter names should indicate `content` or `usage`  names like `a` and `b` are meaningless even in the current context

Comment: the function: `cast()` is recursive, but nothing in the passed parameters is being modified before the function calls itself.  This is not a valid way to implement recursion

Comment: regarding: `int main (int argc, char **argv) {`  When the parameters to `main()` are not used, then the signature: `int main( void )` should be used

Comment: gdb when run against the posted code showed me that the problem is in the function: `summon()` at the 4 iteration, at this line: `return summon(t -> a, key);`  it looks like it tried to use an initialized pointer.  My series of commands:  `gdb untitled` then `bt main` then `run` then `c` then `bt`

Comment: To user3629249 - I understand the thing about content and usage, `a` and `b` should've been replaced with `right` and `left`. I'm not sure what you mean about `cast()` not being recursive - it simply uses recursion to travel down the tree, in much the same way `summon` does. I did not know `int main (void)` was valid - I'll use that in the future. Lastly, all gdb told me was that it received a segfault in `summon`, something I honestly already knew.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this, for example,

```
if (t -> a == NULL) {
    struct tree n = _make(key, value);
    t -> a = &n;
}
```

you're storing a *pointer* to a variable with automatic storage duration into `t->a`. However the lifetime of `n` ends at the `}`, and `t->a` becomes a *dangling pointer*; use of such pointer in any context causes undefined behaviour.

You **need** to use dynamic memory allocation (`malloc` et al) for this task.

Comment: Thank you! The dangling pointer makes sense (especially considering the undefined behavior - the code occasionally ran completely fine). Using `calloc` instead of the dangling pointer, I was able to make the code work.